# find out users who deleted my app

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've created an iPhone app and it's on the App Store, I know the number of downloads and I was wondering if there is a way to find out how many users removed/deleted my app from their phone

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this.  Apple doesn't provide that information.  You could provide an update to your app and see how many people updated the app.  That won't show you everyone that has the app on their devices, but will give you an idea of how many people are conscious about the app enough to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, you need to use APNS Push Notifications. Apple has a Feedback Service which you can listen on to get expired device tokens.